Azure Functions Application Insights integration multiline logs in separate entries
We've created few azure functions and each of them when logging exception to Application Insights, logs stack trace into separate log entry like this:
Picture for application insights
My configuration for serilog:
 }).ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
 {
     var sp = logging.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

     Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Debug)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage", LogEventLevel.Error)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Identity", LogEventLevel.Error)
         .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Flight Data Functions")
         .Enrich.FromLogContext()
         .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Warning)
         .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces, LogEventLevel.Warning)
         .CreateLogger();

     logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
 })

host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}

We are using Serilog:
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Update="serilog.extensions.logging" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Sinks.Async" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Update="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="8.0.0" />


could please tell what do mean by  multiline logs in separate entries.

can you please share the logs in text format.

What is the version of your App?

If you mean functions version it's v4

by multiline logs I mean each line of the stack trace is saved as separate log entry in Application insights like this: 2024-12-04 14:18:00 [2024-12-04T13:18:00.299Z] [13:18:00 FTL] Test Exception Logging 2024-12-04 14:18:00 [2024-12-04T13:18:00.299Z] System.Exception: This is test exception 2024-12-04 14:18:00 [2024-12-04T13:18:00.299Z] at Functions.HealthCheckFunction.ExceptionLoggingTest(TimerInfo timer) in C:\Repos\Functions\HealthCheckFunction.cs:line 32 instead of single log entry. Could not

To enable logging where each line of the stack trace is logged as a separate log entry in Application Insights with Azure Functions using Serilog, follow these steps:
add the below to  format the entire stack trace into a single log entry.
try
{
    // Your function code that may throw an  sample exception .
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 
    string fullExceptionDetails = $"{ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{ex.StackTrace}";
    Log.Fatal(fullExceptionDetails);
}

Refer to this article to configure Serilog for logging in Azure Functions.
In your Serilog configuration, use the custom converter to control logs which are sent to Application Insights. Update Serilog Configuration as below:
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    var sp = logging.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Debug)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Flight Data Functions")
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
            sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(),
            new CustomTelemetryConverter(), 
            LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .CreateLogger();
     logging.AddSerilog();
})

Output:


